# Incorrect Call in bat file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
echo Processing...
echo.
echo Virus detected!
echo.
echo Open Defender.exe(Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT= %=%
If %INPUT%=="Y" CALL a.bat
@echo off
```

a.bat is not starting. What might be the mistake here, can anyone help?

Comment: your condition requires the user to input `"Y"` exactly with quotes to work

Comment: What's the `%=%` part for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
If /i "%INPUT%"=="Y" CALL a.bat
```

quotes are also processed in if conditions.

Comment: @npocmaka you got me - I indeed checked `if /?` if there is really a `/y`

Comment: @Amar30657 it's `/i`, not `/y`

Comment: @Stephan  - ouch.Fat fingers :)